# How to start/stop specific horizon supervisor?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, horizon

I have a horizon question. Is there horizon have a command where i can stop/pause specific supervisor?

for example: i have 5 supervisor running like `supervisor-1, supervisor-2 ... supervisor-5` in horizon.php.

what i want to achieve is how to pause/stop the supervisor-1 for temporary and enable it later?

Answer (score 1):

short answer: you can't. Because master supervisor will re-start all failed supervisor defined on horizon config file. But Laravel do support(not recommend) manage every single supervisor manually. [Mohamed Said wrote a deep dive about how horizon works](https://divinglaravel.com/introduction-to-how-laravel-horizon-works)